# UIWebview contentSize can't fit with phone screen

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview

The same codes of html5 in webview of android runs nature but contentSize more larger on iOS.Is it some wrong with html5 code? May I do some on iOS client to fix it?

Comment: Please, add your code

Answer (score 0):

If you use the UIWebView to load the content, you can set the webview's content to fit. As follow:

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; //true for Swift
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

should size the web page to fit the size of the UIWebView. The user then has the option to zoom in and out of the page. Your problem might be because the webview is not located properly. If your view controller's view fits the screen entirely, add this to your code.

```
webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,Here's my code,if anything else I lost to post,please tell me,TKS!

```
- (UIWebView *)webView
{
  if (!_webView)
 {
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, self.view.width, self.view.height - 45)];
    _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    _webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
 }
    return _webView;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
        <meta content="yes" name="apple-touch-fullscreen">
        <meta mame="renderer" content="webkit">
        <meta content="telephone=no,email=no" name="format-detection">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/type_2/images/engine/style.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/type_2/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/album.css">
        <title>
            相册
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/template.js"></script>
        <script id="itemsTpl" type="text/html">
            {{each list as value i}}
                <li class="captionImg"><img src="{{value}}" alt="{{i}}" title="" /></li>               
            {{/each}}
        </script>        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <i class="i i-1"></i>
            <div><div id="wowslider-container" class="ws_gestures" style="font-size: 10px;"><div class="ws_images"><div style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/854ABED8-D819-4BB0-B772-DD73A64153C7.jpg" alt="0" title="" style="width: 100%;"></div><div class="ws_list" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); width: 300%; display: table; left: 0%;"><div class="ws_swipe_left" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; width: 33.333333333333336%; left: -33.333333333333336%;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/10B68731-D2CA-43A8-9A63-D1C964982BED.jpg" alt="2" title="" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"></div><ul id="items" style="width: 100%;">
                <li class="captionImg" style="display: table-cell; float: none; width: auto; font-size: 0px;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/854ABED8-D819-4BB0-B772-DD73A64153C7.jpg" alt="0" title="" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"></li>               
            
                <li class="captionImg" style="display: table-cell; float: none; width: auto; font-size: 0px;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/5270A5C5-F840-447D-BB5B-585A3E163023.jpg" alt="1" title="" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"></li>               
            
                <li class="captionImg" style="display: table-cell; float: none; width: auto; font-size: 0px;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/10B68731-D2CA-43A8-9A63-D1C964982BED.jpg" alt="2" title="" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"></li>               
            </ul><div class="ws_swipe_right" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; width: 33.333333333333336%; left: 100%;"><img src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1C82725-9EFC-4A90-BFE2-27FD701A0A9A/Documents/Image/854ABED8-D819-4BB0-B772-DD73A64153C7.jpg" alt="0" title="" style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;"></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible;" class="ws_effect"><div class="ws_parts"></div><div class="ws_zoom"></div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></div></div><div class="ws_effect" style="position: absolute; background-size: cover; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;"><div class="ws_effect" style="position: absolute; background-size: cover; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; transform-style: preserve-3d; perspective: 2000px; z-index: 8; overflow: visible;"></div></div><div class="ws_effect" style="overflow: visible; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1280px; height: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transform-origin: 640px 360px 0px; perspective: 2000px; display: none;"></div><div class="ws_video_btn"><div></div></div></div></div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/type_2/images/engine/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/type_2/images/engine/wowslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/type_2/images/engine/script.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var re=null;
            function initData(result){ 
                      
                //result={"time": "3000","list": ["imgs/1.jpg", "imgs/2.jpg","imgs/3.jpg"]};
                re=result;
                //alert(result)
                $("#wowslider-container").html("<div class=\"ws_images\"><ul id=\"items\"></ul></div>");
                var html = template('itemsTpl', result);                
                document.getElementById('items').innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = html;              
                banner(result.time, result.list.length-1); 
            }
            
            function doing(index){                
                if(index==0){                     
                    wowSlider=null;
                    
                    var html="<div class=\"last\"><img src=\""+re.list[re.list.length-1]+"\" /></div>" ;
                    document.getElementById('wowslider-container').innerHTML = html; 
                    // 结束了
                }
            }              

        </script>       
    

</body>
```